# В mysql вставляются лишь определенные даты

Tags: javascript, node.js

Использую библиотеку `mysql` для node.js. Проблема в том, что не все даты вставляются, что очень непонятно, как это вообще работает.

Сразу скажу, на странице библиотеки на гитхабе написано, что создавая объект через `new Date` в js, можно вставлять данные.

Код:

```
connection.connect();
var date1 = new Date('04.07.2016');
var date2 = new Date('23.06.2013');

var queryObject = {
    date1: date1,
    date2: date2
};


connection.query('INSERT INTO test SET ?', queryObject, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;                   
});
connection.end();
```

Что получается в базе данных:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+------------+-------+
| id | date1      | date2 |
+----+------------+-------+
|  4 | 2016-04-07 | NULL  |
+----+------------+-------+
```

Почему дата 04.07.2016 вставилась, а вторая нет?

Comment: А если вторая дата будет 03.06.2013, к примеру, то вставится? (:

Comment: @Suvitruf да, вставилось...а как? Почему?

Comment: Подозреваю, что проблема в формате дат. Ваше `23.06.2013` он пытается распарсить по формату `mm:dd:yyyy` вот и не выходит. Попробуйте на первом месте в дате писать месяц, а не день.

Comment: @Alexxosipov https://xkcd.ru/i/1179_v2.png

Comment: @Alexxosipov *да, вставилось...а как? Почему?* обработчик принимает первую цифру как месяц `04.07.2016` - это 7 апреля 2016, а месяца с номером 23 не существует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, проблема с форматом дат. Я бы предложил с датами работать с библиотекой [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/):

```
var date1Original = '04.07.2016';
var date2Original = '23.06.2013';
const date1 = moment(date1Original , "DD.MM.YYYY").toDate();
const date2 = moment(date2Original , "DD.MM.YYYY").toDate();

var queryObject = {
    date1: date1,
    date2: date2
};
```

В таком случае точно проблем быть не должно.

На самом деле, я не знаю, что будет в итоге после `new Date('04.07.2016')`, так как входная строка должна соответствовать [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15). А там сказано, что строка должна соответствовать ISO 8601: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`.

Или можно передавать день, месяц и год отдельными полями, [как в примерах доки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
new Date(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

Comment: «что будет в итоге» — в нодежс не проверял, но мой фаерфокс вернул специальный объект «Invalid Date»

Comment: ...а вот проверил в ноде — там вернулось `2016-04-06T21:00:00.000Z`, интересненько

Comment: @andreymal поэтому лучше явный конструктор использовать `new Date(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);` или специальные библиотеки вроде `moment`.